# Make PHP return with URL after jQuery upload?

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I am using Hayageek's jQuery upload from: http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php - After the file is done uploading, how can I make it return the URL to the file, but with staying on the same page? Here is my example code:

jQuery upload:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
        url: "upload.php",
        allowedTypes: "jar",
        fileName: "myfile"
    });
});
```

upload.php:

```
<?php
$output_dir = "uploads/";
if (isset($_FILES["myfile"])) {
    $ret = array();

    $error = $_FILES["myfile"]["error"]; 
    if (!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]["name"])) {
        $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"], $output_dir . $fileName);
        $ret[] = $fileName;
    }
    echo json_encode($ret);
}
?>
```

I grabbed all the code from his website. Basically it grabs a file with uploadFile(), then the PHP grabs the file and puts it in the /uploads/ folder. But while I am on the page, how can I make it return back with the URL it uploads to?

I know you can estimate the URL (as the file name won't change, so it will always be http://website.com/uploads/file_name.jar), but I need the server to reply back with the URL once it's done. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'd have to modify the plugin to make it do what you'd like it to do.

Comment: `echo $output_dir . $fileName` ?

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Not exactly. I would have to write extra code yes, but I do not have to modify the plugin. Besides, how would modifying it even work? I can't think of a way.
guest271314 - No. Check the demo on his site for an understanding of what it does.

Comment: Did you want us to write the code for you? Or did you think there was a native method?

Comment: @JayBlanchard - I never want anyone to write my code. I am looking for a way to make the server reply back after the function call is done. I can't seem to find anything related to "PHP reply back to user" anywhere, so my best bet was to ask a simple question. Disgard the plugin I am using. If you visit a .php site and it has a function that does a calculation, how would you make it reply back with the answer after a few seconds? Without reloading the page etc.

Comment: @Snorlax Link to "demo" ? `echo json_encode($ret);` appear to return file name as array ? ; where `fileName: "myfile"` already  defined at `js` ?

Comment: Ah. Normally you'd do something like this with AJAX.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Yep that would be my closest guess too. However, I simply don't know what to do. I could make some tricky workaround crap (sorry for language), where I give each upload an id through the plugin, then I can grab the file using AJAX (because it has an id), but that can be tampered with since it's client side.

Comment: Ask specific Question: _"If you visit a .php site and it has a function that does a calculation, how would you make it reply back with the answer after a few seconds?"_  _"where I give each upload an id through the plugin, then I can grab the file using AJAX (because it has an id"_?

Comment: @guest271314 - Please only respond if you have an answer to my question. You're not helping me a bit here. I appreciate your effort, but please stop :)